# Excel indexing Tabs at file startup?

Tags: excel

This might be a superuser question, if so, please indulge.
I have a rather large (4MB) Excel file with a big amount of tabs (~120).

Issue:
The file takes up to 100 seconds to open

Tried to solve:
All the classics (start in safe mode, delete all volatile functions, delete half the tabs, check/uncheck options advance (hardware acceleration, multithread, etc)
Nothing will do file is very slow to open

Issue I'm trying to solve:
When starting up, the file flickers right next to the macro recording button through

- page 1 of 4
- page 1 of 1
- page 1 of 2
- etc etc

It looks like it's re-indexing each tab or something. Or what could it be ? If so, is there a way to stop that ?

Comment: Try reducing to 10 tabs, and see how slow it is then. You wrote already that you tried reducing to ~60 tabs but that it still was slow. If it's slow at 10 tabs, then probably there's some other issue other than having a very high number of tabs.

Comment: same idea, different path. have 120 tabs? save as 2 x 60 tabs . 60 of the front tabs & 60 of the back tabs.. does the loading time significantly differs? if yes... continue 'breaking' the slower one and find the 'slowness' contributor tab. If not (significantly different), I guess @MarkFernandes method is the troubleshooting path to choose.